# Very simple cron job line

Tags: cron, cron-task

I've never written a cron job cmd before in my life, and I want to make sure its right before I run it on my site so nothing messes up.

There is a json feed that my script autopost.php grabs and adds to my database. Usually I just point my browser to the file so it runs and updates the database but I hear cronjobs can do that automatically for me. Would this be correct?

```
wget -O http://www.domain.com/autopost.php
```

EDIT:

Okay with your help I got it working. However it only work when I added /dev/null after wget -O Why is that?

Comment: Your line lacks at least the timing parameters. How is cron supposed to know when it should execute it ? Read this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the run schedule part of the cron command. you need something like this:

```
* * * * * wget -O http://www.domain.com/autopost.php
```

That says "do a wget every minute. For the syntax, see:
http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference

Comment: I got it working! However it only works when I added /dev/null after wget-O ... Im glad it works but can you explain what /dev/null does?

Comment: I tend to think of /dev/null as a "black hole". It's basically like sending stuff to the garbage. Any output from when the command gets run gets ignored. I'm assuming your command now looks like this?: `* * * * * wget -O http://www.domain.com/autopost.php > /dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

-sure it can !!

follow this link and you will be able to program you job every time you want :
[www.aodba.com](http://www.aodba.com/tut_output_mysql.php?tut=17&page=linux)